# Two Part SEO Friendly URL

Tags: mod-rewrite, seo

I'm in need of an SEO friendly URL for something small. 
The current url looks like `mysite.com/ny.php?c=[COUNTY]&t=23`

With 'c' being a county name, and 't' being the id number of a town.

I found this solution in a previous question:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^blog\/([0-9]+)\/.*$ /blog.php?post=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Which results in `/blog/10/any-old-bit-of-text/` from `/blog.php?post=10`

How could I use something like that, but also have the county in it. 
So `mysite.com/ny.php?c=[COUNTY]&t=23` would become `mysite.com/ny/[COUNTY]/23/town-name` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
RewriteRule ^(ny)/(.+)/(\d+)/(.+)/?$  /$1.php?c=$2&t=$3 [L,QSA]
```

FYI `QSA` flag is mandatory as you are changing the query-string.

even in:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9]+)/.*$ /blog.php?post=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I've never seen the QSA flag in tutorials.  Are you sure it is mandatory?

Comment: @bozdoz If you do not know, Do not comment! read first: [Flag QSA](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) Apache Docs

Comment: It is a good idea. It is not "mandatory". So, to your comment...  :|

Comment: LOL @bozdoz If his URL does not have any other query string.

Comment: Anyway, +1 for suggesting QSA.

Comment: No dice, @ThinkingMonkey! I tried it out, and it doesn't seem to work. Even triple checked to make sure mod_rewrite was working. 

From everything I've been looking at and dissecting, it definitely seems like that should have worked.
I'm not sure if there is any other info that I could provide to help. Other than that `c=` is a county name spelled out (with a capitalized letter) and `t=` is a town id number.

Comment: @Tim Are you geting any errors?

Comment: @ThinkingMonkey I just found the issue! It doesn't like `ny` in there... any thoughts on why? I changed it to `nys` for now.

Comment: @Tim Do you have any other rewrite rules? because `ny` should not be a problem.

Comment: @ThinkingMonkey no sir, I purposely saved my old .htaccess to the side, so I could play with an empty file once I started having problems. With that said, I'm thinking it could likely be something on my host's end, no?

Comment: @ThinkingMonkey Found it. There must be something on the server prohibiting me from renaming to a directory that has the same name as a page. If I rename `/ny.php` to `/nys.php` it allows me to use `ny` as the renamed directory. MAN was that a waste of time for a simple fix. Thank you so much for the help. Stackoverflow has been a resource for me before, but this is the first time I've asked a question, you've been awesome.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question you are asking, you want the mod_rewrite code.

I believe it would be something like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^ny/(.*?)/([0-9]+)/.*$ ny.php?c=$1&t=$2 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Note: I'm pretty sure you don't need to escape the forward slashes. And if ny.php is in the main directory, it doesn't need a forward slash in front of it.

Comment: Too good to be true @bozdoz. It doesn't appear to work.
 Is there anyway for me to display the URL that it is trying to redirect to? Meaning, i may want it to go to `ny.php/?c=Orange&t=5` and in reality it's attempting to redirect to `ny.php//?c=Orange&t=5` or something like adding a space.

Comment: Are you receiving an error?  What page is it bringing you to?  Is there any indication that it is working at all?  There could be a few problems.  Your server may require that you rewrite the base URL, so you could have to include "RewriteBase /" after turning the engine on.  Also, it could be formatted incorrectly.  See if your editing program can detect the format of your .htaccess file, and/or change the format.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @bozdoz. I do know that mod_rewrite is working. I tested it with a redirect for a maintenance page. When I put in the "cleaner" url it just 404's on me.

Comment: So you can rewrite URLs but this particular rewrite rule isn't working?

Comment: Try logging the errors by putting in these lines of code, found on this site: http://www.easymodrewrite.com/guide-logging

Comment: Found the issue @bozdoz. Any idea why it doesn't like the `ny` ? It now works fine with `nys`.